# TimeDistributed: Input to reshape is a tensor with 265000 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 800

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am creating a LSTM model based on [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-neural-machine-translation-system-keras/) as follows:

```py
problem = self.hparams.problem
encoders = problem.feature_encoders

inputs_vocab_size = len(encoders['inputs'].subwords)
targets_vocab_size = len(encoders['targets'].subwords)
hidden_size = self.hparams.model.hidden_size
max_inputs_length = self.hparams.model.max_input_length
max_output_length = self.hparams.model.max_target_length

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(max_inputs_length,))
x = inputs

x = layers.Embedding(inputs_vocab_size, hidden_size, input_length=max_inputs_length, mask_zero=True)(x)
x = layers.LSTM(hidden_size)(x)
x = layers.RepeatVector(max_output_length)(x)
x = layers.LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True)(x)

# Output modality

outputs = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(targets_vocab_size, activation='softmax'))(x)

self.keras_model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

self.keras_model.summary()
```

During training, the loss of the model gets computed like this:

```py
    def loss(self, logits, targets):
        labels = tf.one_hot(targets, self.vocab_size)
        loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels)
        return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

where the `logits` is the model output and `targets` are the training examples.

However, I am getting the following exception during execution:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 265000 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 800
     [[{{node model_fn/model/time_distributed/Reshape_1}}]]
```

Apparently I have an issue with the `TimeDistributed` layer but I don't quite see where the issue is. Where is the `265000`-valued tensor coming from and what am I doing different compared to the [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-neural-machine-translation-system-keras/)?

---

#### Model Summary

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 100)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 2, 64)             512       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 64)                33024     
_________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector (RepeatVector) (None, 100, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100, 64)           33024     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 100, 8)            520       
=================================================================
Total params: 67,080
Trainable params: 67,080
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Hi @displayname, can you please include a minimum reproducible code that can show the error?